# How to run R-script in javascript or angular2 app( Client side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, angular, client

I want to run the R script code directly inside JavaScript to calculate and plot the graph using ggplot2. There is an option opencpu for run and plot the graph directly. but need to transfer the data to that opencpu server.That is not a good solution.Is there any other solution to run R script directly in client side?

Comment: Not without installing the R client.  There has been talk about trying to compile the R interpreter to asm.js or similar, but as far as I know it's just talk.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to install your own opencpu server and use this for processing.
https://www.opencpu.org/download.html

Additionally, you are already using angular2, why don't you use for plotting plotly.js and if your calculation is not so complicated you could also implement it in javascript.